# Why InfluxDB doesn't store data sometime?

Tags: go, influxdb

I recieve data from API and should store it to InfluxDB (2.1.1). But it stote sometime, sometime not. Can't understand why and how to solve it. I am using influxDB golang library.

```
func saveBar(message []byte, writeAPI api.WriteAPI) {
    var (
        data     models.Bar
        barsData []models.Bar
    )
    err := json.Unmarshal(message, &barsData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ERROR Unmarshal", string(message), err)
        return
    }

    for _, data = range barsData {
        p := influxdb2.NewPoint(
            data.Symbol,
            map[string]string{"resolution": data.Resolution},
            map[string]interface{}{"open": data.Open, "high": data.High, "low": data.Low, "close": data.Close, "volume": data.Volume},
            data.DateTime)
        writeAPI.WritePoint(p)
    }
}
```

This piece of code runns in goroutine.

Comment: The error returned from `writeAPI.WritePoint(p)` may give a hint about what the problem is.

Comment: @PenélopeStevens writeAPI is async, so it is not returning anything. But I am logging error from writeAPI.Errors() channel and no error in logs.